# jQuery press button as enter on a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have this text field:

```
<input id="address" type="text" value="">
```

and this button:

```
<input id="ricerca" type="button" class="enter" value="GO!">
```

and jQuery:

```
$("#ricerca").click(function(){
    var e = jQuery.Event('keypress');
    e.which = 13; // #13 = Enter key
    $("#address").focus();
    $("#address").trigger(e);
});
```

I want to simulate the "Enter" press INSIDE the `#address` field, by clicking on the `#ricerca` button. It is necessary that the cursor is inside the `#address` field when I press the button.

Can you please say me where are the errors?

Comment: Do you really need to simulate it that way? can't you just abstract the work into a function and call it in both places?

Comment: I have a search box (`input text`) for google maps API 3 with geolocator and a Javascript onscreen keyboard. When I search on the text input and I press Enter I get the results. So I need the same thing happening with my onscreen keyboard. If there is a simplier way to simulate that, than I can use it!

Comment: `<input id="address" type="text" value="">`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

define what should happen on keypress event for `#address`. Look at this code. Press enter key from insde the text box and then click on the button, both trigger the keypress event.

demo - http://jsbin.com/ocohev/1/edit

```
    $(function () {

        $('#address').keypress(function (event) {
            if (event.which == 13) {
                alert("enter pressed");
                //return false; only if needed
            }
        });

        $("#ricerca").click(function () {
            var e = jQuery.Event('keypress');
            e.which = 13; // #13 = Enter key
            $("#address").focus();
            $("#address").trigger(e);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Jquery code:

```
$("#id_of_textbox").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#id_of_button").click();
    }
});
```